# For Grails Spring Security Core, what is the purpose of the VERSION fields in the USER, GROUP and ROLES tables?

Tags: authentication, grails

I am using the Grails Spring Security Core plugin 2.0-RC4, and I noticed the VERSION field was created in each of the USER, GROUPS and ROLES tables. My database expert is asking me what the VERSION field is for and I could not find any explanation of that field. Can someone tell me what the VERSION field is used for, and how is it used?

Comment: It is a concept in almost any ORM. Think of Oracle Toplink. But I am sure for me it should not be a news of having a `version` column in the table if I am an expert, because I would have already come across those scenarios. :) @Dónal

Comment: You guys are a tough crowd - a creative wrapper for LMGTFY (coincidentally I just tried to use that (un-shortlinked) in another question's answer and learned today that it's not allowed) and a RTFM comment and answer :)

Comment: Note that the plugin generates those domain classes for you, but you should _never_ trust generated code. Read everything that is created for you, and make sure that you (singlular or plural) understand all of it and can justify it. Own your code, whether you wrote it or it was generated. The version column (and optimistic locking) exists in all of them, but if you don't need it (and you probably don't in the role and group tables) then disable that feature and remove the columns. It's yours to delete after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `version` property on all GORM managed classes is used for optimistic locking. You can read more about it in the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#optimisticLockingAndVersioning).

Comment: For more in-depth information about GORM locking it would be a shame not to mention Marc Palmer's excellent [writeup](http://www.anyware.co.uk/2005/2012/11/12/the-false-optimism-of-gorm-and-hibernate/)..